# Magento 2.4.0 url install not loading

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, installation

May I know how to fix Magento 2.4.0 url install not loading?

I don't receive the steps to continue installation.

http://prntscr.com/vxavks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html you can not install magent2.4 with browser installer. You need to use command:

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://localhost/magento2ee \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=magento \
--db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1
```

Comment: Thak you so much

Comment: Hello I have upload my quickinstall theme and nothing work as well

Answer (score 0):

the Web Setup Wizard is removed,
you must use the command line to install or upgrade Magento 2.4.0

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html

Comment: Hello I have upload my quickinstall theme and nothing work as well